# ActiveRecord::PendingMigrationError [running rails4]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

So, I've just added some new migrations to the app and I've run rake db:migrate subsequently. However, I still seem to be getting the below error. I've run the rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development command also. When I refresh the app I get the same error.

```
ActiveRecord::PendingMigrationError

Migrations are pending; run 'rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development' to resolve this issue.
```

Let me know what additional files I can include to help troubleshoot this.

Answer (score 2):

An app reset was the solution for those who come across the same problem :)

Comment: How would you do an app reset? all the information I found suggests restarting either Ruby or Rails using Passenger! Thanks

Comment: +1 for letting us know how you fixed this.  I've added an answer with the actual technique needed.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue using Rails 4 and mysql as the database on Ubuntu 12.04 with apache2 and passenger. I haven't seen this when using sqlite.   The solution was to restart apache:

```
sudo apachectl restart
```

The exact incantation may vary with your distribution, you might need the `service` command.

Answer (score 0):

only what u do , fist go to Git Bash and make "cd name of your folder" and ran this command :

$ rake db:migrate