# ActiveRecord::PendingMigrationError rails 4.0.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

i created a scaffold but i cant migrate it.
when i run `rake db:migrate` i get an error saying 
**rake aborted!** in the terminal, when i run the browser it brings the error below
**Migrations are pending; run 'bin/rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development' to resolve this issue.** but it doesnt resolve it.

am using rails 4.0.3 and i have tried to run `bundle exec rake:migrate` and updating bundle using `bundle update` which all gave me the same error.
 My **schema.rb** is uptodate

[ActiveRecord::PendingMigrationError [running rails4]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17843213/activerecordpendingmigrationerror-running-rails4) recommended an app reset which i did like `rake db:reset`but it also complained of a pending migration i had to complete before the reset.

Comment: Be more specific. Add your migration code here. Check if you ran rake db:create before.

Comment: There mus be a reason for aborting. Do this rake db:migrate --trace then provide more information regarding the abortion.

Comment: Since you are in development drop your database, recreate it, and run all the migration like this: `rake db:drop db:create db:migrate --trace`. What happens if you do that?

Comment: @Octopus-Paul both the development and test dbs exist

Answer (score 0):

i created a products table  using `rails generate scaffold Product \
title:string description:text image_url:string price:decimal` and it created the columns as seen in the class below.

i just realised there was an undefined method 'string'; check code below for the `t.string :\` commenting it out did the job.

`class CreateProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration`

`def change`

> create_table :products do |t|
>
> ```
>  #t.string :\
>   t.string :title
>   t.text :description
>   t.string :image_url
>   t.decimal :price, :precision =>8, :scale =>2
> ```

```
  t.timestamps
end
```